Why Python script quits unexpectedly when trying to open a file, but only when double-clicking as a Python executable?
My use-case 99.9% of the time is to write scripts for myself and run them from the terminal, so this is the first time I'm running into this. But I'm sure it has a super basic/straightforward solution. Consider the following helloworld.py script:

print("hello world!")

file = open("test.txt","r")

x = input()


This script quits unexpectedly when run as a Python executable that I try to double-click. I am using Python 3.12.3 on Windows 11. It winks out so quickly that I don't whether there's an error message shown.
This script runs like a charm from the terminal using
python helloworld.py

and also runs as expected from IDLE. The file test.txt already exists in the directory where this script sits.
I know it quits because it doesn't get to the input() line to hang. The script also runs as expected through double-clicking if the open command is commented out, pausing at input(). So trying to open is the problem.
This would not really be an issue for me, but in my current use-case I'd like to make easy-to-use executables for folks who aren't coders, so getting them to run Python scripts from the terminal is really a no-go for their workflow. More generally this issue is making no sense to me, and I'd really like to understand it.

What happens if you call the executable from command line? It might give you more information than you have currently. Also, well done on a well written question as a new user.

Try import pathlib with open(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "test.txt","r") as file:

@ruohola, you have solved my problem! If you supply this as a post I am happy to give it to mark it as the correct answer (and some more explanation of what is happening here would be amazing if you are willing to do that).

basically, the code is trying to read a file in a folder that does not exist. becuse it is being run from the terminal the error will cause a crash. if it was run from an ide (for example vscode), the debugger would catch this error and explicitly tell you where it is...

The problem is that double clicking the Python file does not use the file's directory as the working directory. (I'm pretty sure it defaults to the home directory on Windows.)
What you should do, is to read the test.txt file with a path relative to the Python script you are executing. This can be achieved easily via Python's pathlib module and the global __file__ variable:
import pathlib

print("hello world!")

with open(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "test.txt") as file:
    ...

x = input()

Note that I'm using open through a context manager, as then the file is closed automatically after the with-block ends, regardless of if any exceptions occur.
Note also that 'r' is the default mode for open, so passing that argument is redundant.
